notepadqq crashes frequently
I have used Notepadqq on the previous versions of Ubuntu with no problem. However, after I upgraded to 24.04, Notepadqq started to crash consistently after a few seconds or minutes of usage. The errors logged to syslog are something like (all the hex values change each time):
kernel: notepadqq-bin[51576]: segfault at 1700000000 ip 0000001700000000 sp 00007ffdde3ac538 error 14 in notepadqq-bin[55b8d1ce2000+31000] likely on CPU 5 (core 5, socket 0)
kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at 0x16ffffffd6.

I tried with another user, but the problem is the same.
I tried to sudo apt purge notepadqq, delete any cached and config related things about Notepadqq and re-install it, but nothing changed.
I tested also on another (virtual) machine and the same problem occurs there too.
The version is v2.0.0-beta+git. And I don't remember the exact version that I was using previously.
Does anybody else have the same problem? What workarounds can be suggested?

There is also snap packages both stable and beta, if you don't have anything against snap

That's something I am considering too. But, since notepadqq seems to have become "abandonware" I might switch to another light text editor (besides the gnome-text-editor which has a lot of bugs and performance issues).

Not the best solution, but I saw the same problem. There's an issue posted about it (several, actually) on the notepadqq GH page.
Proximate cause appears to be auto save - for me it would crash at the moment it was supposed to be saving. Since autosave is one of the main reasons I like notepadqq, it would be pointless to not have it.
What worked for me was to uninstall (sudo apt-get remove notepadqq), and build/install from source.

Thanks. At least, now we know the cause of the problem.
